# how can first activity be chosen at run time based on data?

Tags: android, android-activity, uiviewcontroller

i'm just starting out with Android and i think i'm missing something. 
It seems like in Android you decide at development time which activity will be the first to be displayed in your application.

i would like to write my application in such a way that some kind of a centralized controller starts executing and it decides which activity should be first 
(for example, based on some data obtained from somewhere)

is that possible to do, and if so, how?
thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most folks do it by launching an activity that just picks up the config it needs and then starts up the "real" activity. One hiccup is that the activity first launched will be on the task stack, but if you set android:noHistory="true" for the initial activity the process should be invisible to the user.

Answer (score 4):

The below method can be used for showing tutorial screens on first app launch.

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.LaunchActivity"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".onboarding.OnboardingActivity"/>

<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"/>
```

**LaunchActivity.java**:

```
public class LaunchActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String FIRST_APP_LAUNCH = "com.your.package.name";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (isFirstAppLaunch()) {
            setFirstAppLaunch(false);
            startActivity(new Intent(this, OnboardingActivity.class));
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }

        finish();
    }

    private boolean isFirstAppLaunch() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getBoolean(FIRST_APP_LAUNCH, true);
    }

    private void setFirstAppLaunch(boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(FIRST_APP_LAUNCH, value);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wonder What so tough in this. in the main Activity in the onCreate Method after checking the data starting another activity without setting the view content of Main Activity.